# Maximizing a function subject to uncertainty in the argument

Tags: probability, optimization

Consider the following utility function
$$g(x,u)=uxa+(1-u)(1-x)b$$
where $x\in[0,1]$ is the state variable, $u\in{0,1}$ is the action, and $a,b>0$ are known constants.

The problem of choosing the maximizing action for a given state (and constants) is simply: choose $u=0$ if $(1-x)b>xa$ and $u=1$ otherwise.

Now consider the case where we do not know $x$ with certainty. Instead assume we have a known probability distribution on $x$ denoted by $f_X(x)$. The question I’m interested in is with what probability, call it $p=Pr(u=0)$, do we mix between $u=0$ and $u=1$?

---

**Attempt:** I drew a couple diagrams to try to illustrate the setup. As one varies $p$, imagine a line, pivoting at the intersection of the two functions (lines), moving between $g(x,0)$ and $g(x,1)$.

It seems to me based on this (adhoc) figure, there should be some $p$ that maximizes the expected utility, but I can’t seem to visualize it. At what “angle” is the aforementioned imaginary line?

[image]

Comment: You mention optimizing the expected utility, but depending on the preference you could optimize for a risk-seeking or risk-averse preference level. Are you asking if you should optimize the expected utility?

Comment: Yes, assume risk neutrality.

Comment: You mention a probability $p$ to mix between $u=0$ and $u=1$. Do you suggest a mixed response for a Nash equilibrium like in game theory? If not, what event is $p$ the probability of?

Comment: Sorry I left that part out, assume that $p=Pr(u=0)$. I’m trying to find $p$ such that the risk neutral expected utility is maximized (so I suppose it’s similar to a mixed strategy in GT, but with one agent :P)

Comment: To optimize the expected utility, you can replace $x$ with $EX$ (since $g$ is linear in $x$) and pick $u=0$ if $(1-EX)b > EXa$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, so the optimal decision rule is still deterministic? That is, there is no need to randomize?

Comment: Exactly. Just like in game theory you do not have to randomize if you know what your opponent will do, unless your opponent may deviate to gain an advantage.

Comment: Ah interesting, so (not to go off on a tangent), but mixing really only induces behavior in other players, you never would need to mix if you were the only decision maker.